# Run a script when div is inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jqplot

I have a script that does graphing, using [jqplot](http://jqplot.com).  It works fine when the document is loaded rendering each graph using jquery's .each method.  However, the problem lies when I replace the div with another one when a bar is clicked.  It is suppose to render another graph in the position of the old graph.  It changes the graph but does not execute the script.

The script that loads the items has this function to change all divs to graphs:

```
$("div.barchart").each(function(){
    barChart($(this).attr("id"),$(this).attr("data-xmlurl"));
});
```

is there another way to do this so that it would work when a div is changed too?

#### Update:

Rails generates a script that is ran.  However, it doesn't seem to work when I have this:

```
chart$=$("#<%=params[:chart_id]%>");
chart$.replaceWith("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>"chart_partial"}%>");
barChart(chart$.get(0).attr("id"),chart$.get(0).attr("data-xmlurl"));
```

#### Note:

For reference, the actual source code can be found in the [jquery_cheats project](https://github.com/plowdawg/jquery_cheats/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/jqueryCheats.js)

Comment: You should look into [DOM Mutation Observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could add a listener on the parent element?  Is it OK if the barChart() function gets called more than once?

Maybe something like this:

```
$("div.barchart").parent().on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e) {
    // (or maybe use DOMNodeInserted event instead)
    $("div.barchart[id][data-xmlurl]").each(function() {
        barChart($(this).attr("id"),$(this).attr("data-xmlurl"));
    });
});
```

You can check out my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/KNhuC/) for this here.

Comment: This is the closest I've seen, but calling the barChart function results in some odd rendering.

Comment: Is there a way that you can test if you've already called barChart for a particular element?  If so, you could make it conditional so it doesn't get called more than once on an element.  Obviously you could add a dummy class or attribute, or you could keep a list of the IDs but that's not elegant.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include a jsFiddle showing a less-than-desirable way to do this. Hopefully it illustrates what I'm getting at. Perhaps you could fork it and put in more relevant parts from your scenario then a better solution should be more obvious.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at the fiddle.  However, if you want more relevant code and can be found on github (most of the code). [See the jquery_cheats gem](http://github.com/plowdawg/jquery_cheats)

Comment: I've added your link to your original post (seems like a better place to list it)

Comment: Instead of adding an attribute to the charts (divs) that have been rendered as I showed in jsFiddle, you could alternatively keep a count of how many have been rendered and (assuming they are in order) could then just route the difference between the previous and current counts.

Comment: I thought about using the :empty selector as the divs are essentially empty until jqplot starts putting stuff into them.  The biggest problem I have right now on this solution is it seems to freeze the browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14315/discussion-between-ix3-and-travis-pessetto)

Answer (score 0):

On the current application I'm working on, I'm stuck with version 1.5.2. To get around this, I would unbind and rebind my event and load the initialization in both "ajaxComplete" and "ready". I wasn't able to get the DOM to automatically rebind the event. Delegate is suppose to work like "on", but in my instance I still had to use the below logic.

In short, it would look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitSomethingCool();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    InitSomethingCool();
});

function InitSomethingCool(){
    $(".something").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
        //Unbind and rebind click event.
        alert('You clicked me!');
    });
}
```

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/